Windows Server 2016 - DNS DSNSEC - I'm getting Error 9107 while trying signing
My Windows Server 2016 VPS machine, undergone change in IP address, and transfer into another hardware.
Since then, I tried to update my DNS record, but I got an error related to DNSSEC, and then I unsinged all registered domains.
After finishing the update process, I tried to resign the records, but it kept on failing. I tried all possible options, even went to dns folder, and deleted all old record files...

The Error I'm getting is as following, and I as non-advanced user, couldn't detect any error in event-viewer.

DNS Server 2016 - DNS SEC - Zone Signing Wizard:

The Signing Operation Failed.


Reason: 9107 - One or more of the signing keys for a zone are not accessible to the DNS server. Zone signing will not be operational until this error is resolved.




Hi, does the dns zone is synced with other server and used by any client computer ?

@yagmoth555 there is a secondary machine with Bind9 DNS service running on a Linux server, but it's secondary and this machine... I'm wonder if it read anything from there.
